# Custom Role Authentication ASP .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am really struggling with creating my own user access roles and utilising the IIdentity and IPrincipal classes.

**EDIT**

I have been looking at [this](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1216/implementing-custom-authentication-for-aspnet) but I can't get it to work.

I have created a simple EndUser table with email, password and roles columns. However at the moment, I don't think the roles isn't being parsed through to the IIdentity or IPrincipal and I am unsure of how to do it.

I have looked at several guides and most either rely on VS and the .NET Framework building the basis for you with many clunky looking tables, or they are MVC, which isn't helpful at all.

In my table I have three defined roles which are Client, Sales and Admin, I want certain pages inaccessible to certain users. These are then reflected in my webconfig as Denying access globally but allowing access to certain roles and only if authenticated.

At present the login functionality is working, and users are denied unless logged in but the specific roles are not being taken into account. I have an object stored in session of all of the user data across the site, but "roles" is completely ignored in the web config.

Ultimately I need to do something with uRole, but I am not sure what or how.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks

Login C#:

```
public partial class Login : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void logindd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndUser newEndUser = new EndUser();

        string user = ((TextBox)loginForm1.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
        string conRef = ((TextBox)loginForm1.FindControl("Password")).Text;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string checkIdent = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM EndUser WHERE EndUser.Email=@email AND EndUser.Password=@pass";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkIdent, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", user);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);

                    int chk = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (chk > 0)
                    {
                        //grabbing user role
                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT EndUser.Role FROM EndUser WHERE EndUser.Password=@pass;",con);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                        SqlDataReader sdr = null;
                        sdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                        sdr.Read();
                        string uRole = sdr["Role"].ToString();

                        UserIdentity userr = new UserIdentity(user, true, uRole);
                        userr.Roles.Add(uRole);
                        FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, userr.Roles.ToString());
                        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)));

                        newEndUser.email = user;
                        newEndUser.pass = pass;
                        Session["EndUserObj"] = newEndUser;

                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorLbl.Visible = true;
                        ErrorLbl.Text = "Details are incorrect";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                ErrorLbl.Visible = true;
                ErrorLbl.Text = er.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I was trying to sort this out a few months back. You're currently logging in at the moment, from the code that you've shown I would have to assume that this is a web forms project with pre-built Web Form kit. Therefore you're still using OWIN to login.

Not a code-based walk-through but this is what  you need to do, I'm happy to assist further if you get stuck:

1. Change the global.asax so that it authenticates the user on `Application_AthenticateRequest` and remove anything related to OWIN in it's methods.
2. You need a class to derive from `IIdentity` and accept params of username, authtype and isAuthenticated and a class to derive from `IPrincipal` which will contain the derived `IIdentity`, and the role. I went for public getter and setters and private variables of things like name, is auth etc.
3. A class to get the identity of the user, this where you'll get against the password and username and create an instance of the derived `IIdentity` to set, also check against the information held within the database.
4. The global method `Application_AthenticateRequest` will need to verify the user on each page load, so you need to have a method that creates an instance of the derived `IPrincipal` to check whether the user is authenticated by grabbing the derived `IIdentity` and checking what role the user is in.
5. Modify the webconfig so that it uses `FormsAuthentication`, doesn't use OWIN, so within `AppSettings` add `<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>` as I assume you have a pre-built site, don't try and remove OWIN, just disable it.

You should then be able to login and the custom roles you declare will then be used by the derived `IIdentity` which in turn will be acknowledged by the webconfig location based security.

Hope this helps you and others.